# Fight and first strike

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I was playing a game earlier and my opponent had a [Drana, Liberator of Malakir](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Drana%2C%20Liberator%20of%20Malakir) that was a 4/3 and wanted to use a sorcery to fight [Kozilek's Channeler](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=401936) that was a 4/4.

We were wondering if the Channeler would die first because of First Strike? Or would it not be counted as it wasn't combat?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First Strike does not apply because it isn't combat.

> **701.10d** The damage dealt when a creature fights isn’t combat damage.
>
> **702.7a** First strike is a static ability that modifies the rules for the combat damage step.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought but we really weren't sure